# VPN connection doesn't work on VMWARE

Tags: vmware, vpn

I use vmware for my dev work with ubuntu 12.04.
I just installed KDE for add my vpn connection, the configuration seems ok.

But I can't find how to connect my interface eth0 with my VPN.

When I try

> nmcli con up id "VPN NAME CONNECTION"

I have this error

> (process:2604): GLib-WARNING **: (/build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.3/./glib/gerror.c:390):g_error_new_valist: runtime check failed: (domain != 0)
>
> Error: No suitable device found: no active connection or device.

I read many thread and no one help with my trouble.
Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: That error generally means eth0 is not up, not managed by network-manager or has a VPN on it already. Is any of these three conditions true?

Comment: Eth0 is up
How I can check if my eth0 is managed by network-manager ?
I don't have VPN on it

Comment: Did you set it up with networkmanager? Does `nmcli con | grep ethernet` list it?

Comment: nmcli con | grep ethernet didn't list any interface.
I never user network manager, vmware find automaticly my card

Answer (score 0):

NetworkManager cannot manage VPN connections on devices it doesn't also manage, so you have two options here

- Use NetworkManager to manage your eth0 wired connection and the VPN
- Don't use NetworkManager to manage either, manage them both manually

I'm afraid you cannot mix and match this.